# Two checkbox in recyclerview changing state when scrolling

Tags: android, checkbox

**Edit**

Solved issue by removing two lines

```
holder.checkbox.setChecked(mListenerList.get(position).isSelected());
holder.checkbox.setChecked(mListenerList.get(position).isSelected2());
```

And By Adding

```
  @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

**I am not editing my original code for future developers.**

**Main Question before Edit Start from Here**

I am working on fantasy cricket app where I am selecting the captain and vice captain from a list of 11 player.
I am using a checkbox for selecting the captain and vice captain.

The selection of checkbox is working fine with my code, but the issue is when I select 1st player as a captain(C) and 2nd player as Vice-Captain(VC) and then scroll the list the checkbox state is changing and showing other player selected.

So is there any right way to do that thing?
I have tried many way they are working when there is single checkbox but in my case there is two and only one can be select from the list.

Please refer to the attached screenshots on the bottom for clarity.

#### Adapter Class

```
public class AdapterFinalTeamList extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterFinalTeamList.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<BeanDBTeam> mListenerList;
    Context mContext;
    private  CheckBox lastChecked = null;
    private  int lastCheckedPos = 0;

    private  CheckBox lastChecked2 = null;
    private  int lastCheckedPos2 = 0;

    private RadioButton lastCheckedRB = null;
    private RadioButton lastCheckedRB1 = null;

    TextView PreviousCaptain = null;
    TextView PreviousVC = null;


    public AdapterFinalTeamList(List<BeanDBTeam>              mListenerList, Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        this.mListenerList = mListenerList;

    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_PlayerName,tv_SelectCaptain,tv_SelectViceCaptain, tv_PlayerTeamName, tv_PlayerPoints,tv_TeamNumber;
        ImageView im_PlayerImage,im_onetwox;
        CheckBox checkbox,checkbox2;

        RadioGroup radiogroup;
        RadioButton radio,radio2;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            tv_PlayerName =view.findViewById(R.id.tv_PlayerName);
            tv_PlayerTeamName = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_PlayerTeamName);
            tv_PlayerPoints = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_PlayerPoints);

            im_PlayerImage = view.findViewById(R.id.im_PlayerImage);
            im_onetwox = view.findViewById(R.id.im_onetwox);


            tv_TeamNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_TeamNumber);
            tv_SelectViceCaptain = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_SelectViceCaptain);
            tv_SelectCaptain= view.findViewById(R.id.tv_SelectCaptain);
            checkbox= view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            checkbox2= view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
            radiogroup= view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
            radio= view.findViewById(R.id.radio);
            radio2= view.findViewById(R.id.radio2);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mListenerList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.adapter_final_list, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {



        String id = mListenerList.get(position).getMatchId();

        String arrayList = (mListenerList.get(position).getPlayerData());
        try {
            JSONObject job = new JSONObject(arrayList);

            String PlayerName = job.getString("name");
            String PlayerImage = job.getString("image");
            String PlayerPoints = job.getString("player_points");
            String PlayerCredit = job.getString("credit_points");
            String TeamShortName = job.getString("team_short_name");

            String team_number = job.getString("team_number");
            String player_shortname = job.getString("player_shortname");
            holder.tv_TeamNumber.setText(team_number);
            // PlayerTeam= job.getString("short_name");

            holder.tv_PlayerName.setText(PlayerName);

            holder.tv_PlayerPoints.setText(PlayerPoints);
            holder.tv_PlayerTeamName.setText(TeamShortName);


            Glide.with(activity).load(Config.PLAYERIMAGE + PlayerImage)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(holder.im_PlayerImage);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
holder.checkbox.setChecked(mListenerList.get(position).isSelected());
        holder.checkbox.setTag(new Integer(position));

        holder.checkbox.setChecked(mListenerList.get(position).isSelected2());
        holder.checkbox2.setTag(new Integer(position));



        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                int clickedPos = ((Integer) cb.getTag()).intValue();
                    holder.checkbox2.setChecked(false);

                    if (cb.isChecked()) {
                        if (lastChecked != null) {
                            mListenerList.get(lastCheckedPos).setSelected(false);
                            lastChecked.setChecked(false);
                        }
                        else if (clickedPos==position){
                            lastCheckedPos = clickedPos;
                            lastChecked = cb;
                            lastChecked.setChecked(true);
                        }
                        lastCheckedPos = clickedPos;
                        lastChecked = cb;
                    } else
                        lastChecked = null;

                    try {
                        lastChecked.setChecked(true);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    mListenerList.get(clickedPos).setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                    CaptainId = mListenerList.get(position).getPlayerId();


            }
        });
    holder.checkbox2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                int clickedPos = ((Integer) cb.getTag()).intValue();

                holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);

                    if (cb.isChecked()) {
                        if (lastChecked2 != null) {
                            lastChecked2.setChecked(false);
                            mListenerList.get(lastCheckedPos2).setSelected(false);
                        }
                        else if (clickedPos==position){
                            lastChecked2 = cb;
                            lastCheckedPos2 = clickedPos;
                            lastChecked2.setChecked(true);
                        }

                        lastChecked2 = cb;
                        lastCheckedPos2 = clickedPos;
                    } else
                        lastChecked2 = null;

                    try{
                lastChecked2.setChecked(true);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mListenerList.get(clickedPos).setSelected2(cb.isChecked());
                ViceCaptainId = mListenerList.get(position).getPlayerId();

                }

        });


    }

}
```

**adapter_final_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res /android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/RL_PlayerListMain"
    android:elevation="0dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_TeamNumber"

    android:visibility="invisible"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/im_PlayerImage"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/RL_Name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/im_PlayerImage"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Player Name"
    android:id="@+id/tv_PlayerName"
    android:textColor="#1e1e1e"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_PlayerName">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="IND"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_PlayerTeamName"
        android:textColor="#1e1e1e"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#8e8e8e"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="55 Points"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tv_PlayerPoints"
        android:textColor="#8e8e8e"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/RL_Credit"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="C"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_captain_vc_back"
        android:id="@+id/tv_SelectCaptain"
        android:textColor="#1e1e1e"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_SelectViceCaptain"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="C"
        android:textColor="#1e1e1e"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="VC"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#1e1e1e"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_vc_selector"
        android:id="@+id/checkbox2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/onex_icon"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/im_onetwox"
        />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/im_onetwox"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_SelectViceCaptain"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="C"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/radio"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="VC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_vc_selector"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/radio2"/>
    </RadioGroup>



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="VC"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_SelectCaptain"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"        android:background="@drawable/circle_captain_vc_back"
        android:id="@+id/tv_SelectViceCaptain"
        android:textColor="#1e1e1e"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />


</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#8e8e8e"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RL_PlayerListMain"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

#### Selecting C and VC

[image: 1. Selecting C and VC]

#### After scrolling top to bottom and bottom to top

[image: 2. After scrolling top to bottom and bottom to top.]

Please ignore Radio group. My code is working fine with checkbox, it's only creating issues when scrolling.

Comment: you are not getting `captain` selection properly.

Comment: does the 
`holder.checkbox.setChecked(mListenerList.get(position).isSelected());
        holder.checkbox.setTag(new Integer(position));

        holder.checkbox.setChecked(mListenerList.get(position).isSelected2());
        holder.checkbox2.setTag(new Integer(position));`
the 3rd line must be `holder.checkbox2` instead of `holder.checkbox` right?

Comment: @farhana I am getting the value. the only thing is when I am scrolling checkbox state changed and showing other position selected.

Comment: Override _getItemViewType()_ and _getItemId()_ methods in adapter.

Comment: If I right, your `holder.checkbox` is call `setChecked`  2 times and go wrong if `IsSelected2` = false and `IsSelect` = true

Comment: its because your views are being recycled every time you scroll and items are losing their states...

Comment: this line of code resolved my problem try this : holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

Comment: @Piyush now worked with override methods.

Comment: @asifali not working with two checkbox

Comment: @Aayushri does my work help?

Comment: @ToraCode not worked. Can you help with other solution. Also Please refer to screenshot for properly understand my problem. I think everyone is missing there is 2 checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

For **`checkbox`** you need to use **`checkbox.OnCheckedChangeListener()`** instead of **`checkbox.setOnClickListener()`**

Follow this steps

add a new Boolean variable in your **`BeanDBTeam`** class

```
public class BeanDBTeam
{               
    boolean isChecked;    

    public boolean getisChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    public void setIsChecked(boolean flag) {
        isChecked= flag;
    }
}
```

Now inside you **`onBindViewHolder()`** add below code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    BeanDBTeam  bean = mListenerList.get(position).getisChecked()

    // check here the flag and status of checkbox  based on flag
    holder.checkbox2.setChecked(bean.getisChecked());

    holder.checkbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
              // set flag of checkbox status  in your list when user check or uncheck the checkbox
             bean.setIsChecked(isChecked);
             notifyDataChanged();
          }
    }); 
 }
```

Comment: Should use `notifyItemChanged(position)` instead of `notifyDataChange()`

Comment: Nilesh, congrats for 30k in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

As **@Nilesh** suggested you , to use the `Bean` class for `checkbox` state remember functionality like below:

```
 /**
 * CheckType ==>>1 For the first checkbox
 * CheckType ==>>2 For the second checkbox
 * CheckType ==>>0 For the None
 */         
public class BeanDBTeam
{
    int checkType;


    public int getCheckType() {
        return checkType;
    }

    public void setCheckType(int checkType) {
        this.checkType = checkType;
    }
}
```

Inside the **`MyViewHolder`** you need to apply the **`setOnCheckedChangeListener`** listener and get position from the **`getAdapterPosition()`** like below

```
 public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_PlayerName, tv_SelectCaptain, tv_SelectViceCaptain, tv_PlayerTeamName, tv_PlayerPoints, tv_TeamNumber;
    ImageView im_PlayerImage, im_onetwox;
    CheckBox checkbox, checkbox2;

    RadioGroup radiogroup;
    RadioButton radio, radio2;


    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        tv_PlayerName = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_PlayerName);
        tv_PlayerTeamName = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_PlayerTeamName);
        tv_PlayerPoints = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_PlayerPoints);

        im_PlayerImage = view.findViewById(R.id.im_PlayerImage);
        im_onetwox = view.findViewById(R.id.im_onetwox);


        tv_TeamNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_TeamNumber);
        tv_SelectViceCaptain = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_SelectViceCaptain);
        tv_SelectCaptain = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_SelectCaptain);
        checkbox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkbox2 = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
        radiogroup = view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
        radio = view.findViewById(R.id.radio);
        radio2 = view.findViewById(R.id.radio2);

        /**
         * NOW WE APPLY THE setOnCheckedChangeListener functionality for the checkboxlistener
         */

        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // set flag of checkbox status  in your list when user check or uncheck the checkbox
                if (checkbox) {
                    YOUR_ARRAYLIST.get(getAdapterPosition()).setCheckType(1);
                }
                else {
                    YOUR_ARRAYLIST.get(getAdapterPosition()).setCheckType(0);
                }
                notifyDataChanged();
            }
        });

        checkbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // set flag of checkbox status  in your list when user check or uncheck the checkbox
                if (checkbox) {
                    YOUR_ARRAYLIST.get(getAdapterPosition()).setCheckType(2);
                }
                else {
                    YOUR_ARRAYLIST.get(getAdapterPosition()).setCheckType(0);
                }
                notifyDataChanged();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

And inside the **`onBindViewHolder`** we need to set the `Checkbox` according to the selection like below

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    BeanDBTeam  bean = mListenerList.get(position).getisChecked()

    // check here the flag and status of checkbox  based on flag
    if(bean.getCheckType()==0) {
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
        holder.checkbox2.setChecked(false);

    }
    else if(bean.getCheckType()==1) {
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
        holder.checkbox2.setChecked(false);

    }
    else if(bean.getCheckType()==2) {
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
        holder.checkbox2.setChecked(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: I have two checkbox in a item and only one can be select for example if I select 1st item as C and then I click on same item on VC then C should be unchecked and VC sholud be checked and Vice versa.

Comment: Not Worked. Do you have any other solution. Also please refer to the screenshots for understanding my problem. It will be great if you solve this problem.

Comment: @Aayushri I have updated the solution..Please check  and let me know in case of concern

Comment: What is the use of notifyDataSetChanged(); here.
This is generating exception in my code.

Comment: What exception are u getting there? , u can also use the `notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition())` in place of the `notifyDataSetChanged()`... The use of these is that , we need to notify the arraylist that what changed happened

Comment: I have edited my post, Issue resolved with commenting 2 lines and adding override method.

Answer (score 0):

This is what recycling behaviour is, You can use other answer that are also correct but as you are having limited entries in your list you can actually disable recycling your recyclerview. Use below code in your adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CommentViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
}
```